# Jenkins with mix of Azure and On-premise agents

Tags: azure, jenkins, devops

I'd like to setup Jenkins with a mix of Azure and on-premise agents. Ideally I would like the Jenkins master to be in Azure and have on-premise agents connect to that master, however the on-premise agents will not be publicly exposed but will be able to access the Jenkins master on Azure.

Is it possible to have a mix of Azure and on-premise agents? Is it possible to have the on-premise agents talk to a Jenkins master on Azure? If so, how would I configure this and what would I need to know?

Comment: Any update for the question? Helpful or not?

Comment: It looks like it is possible. I haven't been able to try this as our work network has firewalls preventing me from connecting the on-premise agents to the master in Azure. Still working to get this opened up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to create an Azure VPN and then the on-premise agent could connect the Azure master agent through its private IP. In this way, you do not need to expose the on-premise agent to the public.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible. jenkins doesnt care where agents are located. for jenkins agent to talk to master on Azure they'd need to be able to communicate. Normally via ssh, I'm not quite sure if master talks to slaves or vice versa, but either way its possible to achieve using proper networking on Azure\on-premise.

If you'd need to connect to Azure master from agents, you'd need to assign public ip address to the master, in the reverse scenario you'd need to expose some port on your infrastructure that can be used to talk to your agents.

Another alternative is using site-to-site VPN\express route, to establish direct connection to on-premise stuff (this is a bit harder to achieve, but might be beneficial in the long run).